# Alocação de ordem SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

É possível eu realocar esse ultimo produto com ID 21, para o campo que demarquei em vermelho?

[image: dados]

---

Na verdade, veja bem.
Não é por TOC, e sim algo funcional, em nosso site aonde esta pegando como referencia o banco, esta mostrando da forma em que esta no banco, e por isso a necessidade de organizar pro segmentos.
Esse ultimo produto foi inserido após a finalização das outras inserções, por isso ele não esta segmentado.
Tenho uma coluna nmOrdem que esta ordenado corretamente, mas ainda continua errado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é só ordenar pelo campo `stProduto` ou eu não entendi sua dúvida?

Comment: mas o problema que já esta na base, e essa base ela aponta para um site dos produtos e eu precisava que esse ultimo produto ficasse junto com o segmento dele de papel higienico

Comment: Me parece, já que você não forneceu as devidas informações, que o campo `id` é do tipo auto-incremento. Quem criou a base de dados utilizou tal tipo de campo (chave artificial) para não se preocupar com alguma ordem específica de armazenamento dos registros. Aliás em qualquer SGBD se você quer garantir a recuperação dos dados em alguma determinada ordem deve sempre utilizar a cláusula `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

É possível, mas não é recomendado. Para fazer isso teria que mudar o `id` dele e isso é algo que não deve fazer, teria que mudar o `id` de diversas outras linhas de dados, e em certo cenário de todos. E aí todas referências para esses dados estariam inválidas. Teria que mudar em todo banco de dados, aplicações, ou qualquer coisa externa que tenha pego essa referência pelo `id`. Então não faça, deixe como está que está bom.

Note que você não pode organizar como o banco de dados coloca informações dentro dele, não é do seu interesse, é detalhe de implementação e ele pode mudar como quiser.

O que eu acho que está pensando é que esses dados estão organizados do jeito que está vendo. Isso é só uma apresentação, uma aplicação que mostra dados, ela resolveu que iria mostrar assim, ela deve ter outras formas de mostrar de outros jeitos.

Você pode mandar mostrar de outro jeito aí mesmo ou em outros lugares. Essa apresentação provavelmente veio de uma *query* SQL, e pelo que está descrevendo teria que fazer algo como:

```
SELECT FROM Produtos ORDER BY stProduto
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/OrderBy2.sql).

Chutei o nome da tabela. Pronto, está apresentando do jeito que quer. Mas não foi feita nenhuma realocação. Para realocar poderia fazer um *script* de classificação (*sort*) que grave os dados e não apenas os apresente, mas tem todos os problemas que eu disse antes.

A necessidade de colocar tudo junto não faz sentido e não é como um banco de dados funciona. A vontade de fazer isso deve acontecer ou por desconhecer a natureza do banco de dados ou por ter TOC, que eu compreendo, mas ainda não deve fazer, não sendo isso é a primeira.

Claro que se a tabela acabou de ser criada e não há qualquer referência a ela em lugar algum dentro ou fora do banco de dados até poderia fazer esse *sort* para atender esse gosto, mas sempre ocorrerá algo do tipo e não poderá fazer nas outras vezes, então melhor não perder tempo, foque na apresentação.